# Mysql Right join with mutiple condtion not working

Tags: mysql, join

i have two table table1 and table2 and when right joining the table2 with table1 and i am not getting the row. here i have attached the fiddle link also

[Fiddle ink](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60c648/3)

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`orderid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `table2` ( `fields_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `table1_order_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , `field_value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `fname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`fields_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`orderid`) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'karthi', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'karthi', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'selva', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'salem', 'city');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'chennai', 'city');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'mumbai', 'city');

select table1.*
from table1 
right JOIN table2 ON (
        table2.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 
        AND 
            ( table2.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'name' ) 
        AND ( 
            table2.field_value LIKE '%salem%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'city' 
        ) 

    ) 

    where 1 group by table1.orderid
```

Above i  wrote select query but it returns null result
but i am expecting output like below,

**orderid**
1

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do/which row(s?) you want to get/what the expected output is. Currently, your join condition includes `table2.fname = 'name' AND table2.fname = 'city'`, which is obviously never true.

Comment: Not getting what row & why would you? You are getting the result you are asking for, so until you explain your expectations what do you expect us to be able to tell you but, that's how SQL works? It's very good that in a code question you gave much of a (well-formatted, fiddled, tagged etc) [mre]. Please also give desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages) & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Hi @solarflare philipxy I want to get the orderid result as 1 because of my right join condition is true

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But your comment is unintelligible--Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please act my last comment which is an edited version of an earlier one & was posted as you posted your last comment. PS But Solarflare's comment answered your question, didn't it? Your ON is always *false*. Do you want `(...) or (...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `AND` clause with `OR` clause and you will get two records as follows:

```
select table1.*
from table1 
right JOIN table2 ON
        table2.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 
    where 
            ( table2.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'name' ) 
        OR ( 
            table2.field_value LIKE '%salem%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'city' 
        ) 

    group by table1.orderid
```

Comment: Yes @Ishpreet, but it returns two rows. can i change to work like and condition

Comment: If you write `AND` condition, then think of it as : `WHERE field_value  LIKE '%karthi%' AND field_value LIKE '%salem%'`. Think about this condition, can field_value have two values karthi and salem at the same time? Think of find out on one table only without joining, can you get any result with `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE field_value  LIKE '%karthi%' AND field_value LIKE '%salem%'`. Think about only just this simple query.

Comment: Actually we want to know what output you are expecting, then we can better help you with query. Just show data you are expecting.

Comment: Hi @Ishpreet, i am expecting my query to return the orderid 1

Comment: Means just one row, instead of two?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check updated answer. You will get result `orderid 1`

Comment: Yes, your query returns table1.orderid => 1,2, but i need results to be  table1.orderid => 1

Comment: Query is giving output `orderid 1` only, check fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60c648/19. May be your table has more records, but here only those records which you have shared in your fiddle link in question and query in fiddle is giving output based on records available in table.

Comment: Could you check on following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af03de/3 , but it's returning the table1.orderid => 1, 2 and i am expecting the results to be table1.orderid => 1

Comment: The link you have shared now is returning two records because here `field_value='karthi' and fname='name'` exists two times but with different `table1_orderid`, that's why it is returning `1 and 2`.  It definitely returns two orderid because your condition is true for orderid 1,2 and have same` field_value fname` pair. If still you want single record, add one more line at end of query 'LIMIT 0,1';

Comment: The data you have shared on question via fiddle link contains `field_value='karthi' and fname='name'` only once, that's why fiddle data on question will return only one record.

Comment: Hi Ishpreet, if i am adding the imit 0,1 it won't work, it always returns only one result, i am expecting for exampe below fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ceaf3/2 to return the results table1.orderid => 1, 2 but currently it returns table1.orderid 1,2,3

Comment: The fiddle you have just shared in above comment is returning three records because here same `field_value='karthi' and fname='name'` contains three times but with different orderid. It will return three records.

Comment: if i change or condition to and condition why it was returing the empty results, ( table2.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'name' ) 
        AND ( 
            table2.field_value LIKE '%salem%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'city' 
        ) , or how do i change this query to returns the table1.orderid to 1,2

Comment: Please read second comment again to find answer of this question why it is not returning output.

Comment: Thanks ishpreet, for your help now I am understood clearly